# How do I stop bx-slider on next control click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, bxslider

I need to stop the bx-slider autoslideshow when the next button gets clicked, I have the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    elementSlider=$(".monitor_slider").bxSlider({
    auto: true, pager: false,
});
$(".monitor_slider_container .bx-wrapper .bx-next").click(function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent !== undefined){
            elementSlider.stopAuto();
        }
    });
});
```

No erros, but the slider keeps on changin automatically.

Any help will be really appreciated.

And forgive my bad english.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10689253/2427193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Now you can just add the parameter `stopAutoOnClick: true` and it will stop on click of the controls Next/Prev

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true,
  stopAutoOnClick: true
});
```

Source : https://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rikard, I needed to write my own controls. The code now looks like this and the problem is solved.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    elementSlider=$(".monitor_slider").bxSlider({
    auto: true, pager: false,
});

    $(".bx-next").toggleClass("px-next");
    $(".px-next").toggleClass("bx-next");
$(".px-next").click(function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent !== undefined){
            elementSlider.goToNextSlide();
            return false;    
        }
    });

    $(".bx-prev").toggleClass("px-prev");
    $(".px-prev").toggleClass("bx-prev");
    $(".px-prev").click(function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent !== undefined){
            elementSlider.goToPreviousSlide();
            return false;    
        }
    });
});
```

It seems that when you use the goToNextSlide and goToPreviousSlide functions the autoshow stops.